# How to turn Polyglossia shorthands off

Tags: polyglossia

This sounds like a simple question, but the key `babelshorthands=false` seems to be buggy (run with XeLaTeX)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[babelshorthands=false]{german} 
\begin{document}
\the\catcode`"

\end{document}

    .aux with english only
    \relax 
    \select@language {english}
    \@writefile{toc}{\select@language {english}}
    \@writefile{lof}{\select@language {english}}
    \@writefile{lot}{\select@language {english}}

    .aux with german and english
    relax 
    \catcode `"\active 
    \select@language {english}
    \@writefile{toc}{\select@language {english}}
    \@writefile{lof}{\select@language {english}}
    \@writefile{lot}{\select@language {english}}
```

Secondary question, where is `active@prefix` defined?